# R-Referring to variable value in r shiny

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I am trying to get column names from a select input variable in the ui section of shiny app as follows:

```
 server <- function(input,output){
    output$plot1 <-renderPlot(
    {
    x <- input$select_input_ID
    plot(df$x,df$col2_name)
    }
   )
}
```

I tried using get(x)

Comment: Try `df[x]`, that can handle the quoted input.

Comment: I'm interested to see if this worked ^^

Comment: @JohnPaul Thanks ! that worked

Comment: Depending on whether you want a vector or a matrix column, you can consider using `df[[x]]` as well.